# Integrate blockchain using Hyperledger into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperledger, blockchain, smartcontracts

I am looking for assistance with integrating blockchain smart contracts using hyperledger into an already existing wordpress website.

Comment: You have to make distributed application using Web3 Library

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger have many offering i.e. Fabric, Sawtooth, Indy etc.
Fabric is popular one and can have multiple implementation scenario so I suppose you would go with that.

Hyperledger Fabric provide REST API support by which you can communicate with your existing application(for example a Wordpress site) with some modification to your current code. 
If you want to do Proof of Concept at the moment you should go with Hyperledger composer, because it is easy to implement and learn.

this may help you for PoC model.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/introduction/introduction

remember that your front end of wordpress will remain same but back-end will change since, a transaction now occur in blockchain. It is also important to deploy the blockchain in a distributed environment for the production level scenario.